# On duplicate multiple columns key containing datetime doesn't work

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-update

I have table like this in my database:

```
someID (int) | date (datetime) | a | b |
---------------------------------------
```

where someID and date are my primary key. Then I'm using query like this one:

```
INSERT INTO theTable SET date='2014-12-07 11:00:00', someID = 25, a=1, b=0 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = a + 1
```

The problem is that if I change the someID value the database will create a new record but it doesn't care about the date if someID is the same, even if it is also declared as primary key.

Do you have an idea how to fix my problem?

---

edit my full schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `someId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`someId`,`date`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Comment: "where someID and date are my primary key". Care to share full schema?

Comment: I'm not sure how to post full schema having only phpmyadmin access with non english language

Comment: DESCRIBE tableName would help.

Comment: Here you go, the full schema of table is in first post.

Comment: Is someId == action_id ?

Comment: It seems to be working as intended in my Local server. You sure you used Exact date value to force a=a+1 ? I mean, I used same query twice and the value of a = 2

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I'll try to repeat this on sql fiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fededd/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From now on it works. It seems that I had an extra index key which caused the problem.